# Spring MVC with Security & REST endpoint gives a 403 "Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found"

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Java Spring-boot microservice where I have an admin website and REST endpoints.  The website is accessed at myserver.com/serverwebpages and the REST web service is at myserver.com/api/restendpoints.  I am using Spring MVC with login security and CSRF on the web side and HMAC Authorization on the REST endpoint side.  I have @Controller annotation on the website side and @RestController annotation for the REST web service.  The website works fine and the webservice works fine with GET's.  However, I just tried a DELETE and got a 403, error:forbidden, message:"Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found".  It looks like the MVC security is seeing REST webservice requests and calling out the CSRF error because I have not provided a CSRF number.  Of course, I do provide CSRF's on the web page side for MVC cross-scripting security.  Anyone know how to fix this?  Do I need to create a separate microservice with a different port?

Comment: Are you getting the same error in POST or PUT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out a solution to the problem using Spring MVC.  So I just created 2 separate microservices on the same AWS instance.  One microservice with port number 443 handles the web services and uses Spring MVC.  The other microservice with port 8443 handles all of the REST API calls with no Spring MVC.  This worked perfectly.  Disappointed that I could not find an answer but had to move on.

Answer (score 0):

When you call DELETE method, they need CSRF token. Maybe your DELETE API doesn't carry CSRF token. You need to add CSRF token in Request Header. 
Adding CSRF in Header is depends on Ajax framework. If your combination is Spring-Security + Thymeleaf + jQuery, then refer Spring Security Document : 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax

Comment: I do understand what you are saying.  I support CSRF's on the website side.  However, the website service and REST webservice are completely separate resources.  Neither one knows anything about the other.  The REST service is not using MVC security.  It's just a plain old REST endpoint service with its own HMAC Authorization security.  The only thing they have in common is they run in the same microservice.  Is running a website with MVC security and REST service on the same microservice not compatible?  It does not make sense for my application security to turn off CSRF's.  Your thoughts?

Comment: A simple fix would be to create 2 spring boot microservices and run the website microservice-A on 443 and the REST webservice microservice-B on 8443.  However, if I can get them to run in the same microservice that would be more convenient.  Your thoughts?